# Adding a column to existing PostgreSQL table with constraint and default value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to add a column `qc_isotope` to an existing psql table `sensitivity`. The value of qc_isotope must not be NULL and should either equal 'TC' or 'TL' with a default value of 'TC' given to all existing rows in `sensitivity`. I am fairly new to Postgresql and am unsure how to do this.

Here is my attempt which is unsuccessful

```
ALTER TABLE sensitivity 
ADD COLUMN qc_isotope VARCHAR(2) CHECK 'NOT NULL' DEFAULT 'TC';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE sensitivity 
   ADD qc_isotope VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT 'TC' 
       CHECK (qc_isotope IN ('TC', 'TL')) NOT NULL;
```

The full list of syntax options etc for check constraints is described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html). There is also further information on alter table add column statements [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

Comment: You forgot the `NOT NULL` constraint

Comment: @ChrisProsser - It does not seem to like the ENABLE keyword

Comment: @moadeep Apologies, I have corrected the answer above. I am also just checking whether the not null constraint is required in addition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are quote right, I had assumed the `in` would handle this, but it does not. I am corrective above, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @moadeep Please note the further correction above as a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, the not null constraint is still required in addition.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it compatible with Postgres (I incorrectly changed the question's tag to `oracle`  so this is on me). I also replaced the links to the Oracle manual with links to the Postgres manual.

Answer (score 2):

A different appoach: create a `DOMAIN` and use that as a data type for qc_isotope.
This will come in handy if the data type uccurs in more than one place: the constraint won't have to be repeated.

```
CREATE DOMAIN QC_ISO VARCHAR(2) CHECK (value IN ('TC', 'TL' ))
        ;

CREATE  TABLE sensitivity
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        );

ALTER TABLE sensitivity
        ADD COLUMN qc_isotope QC_ISO NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TC'
        ;

INSERT INTO sensitivity(qc_isotope) VALUES ('AA') ;
INSERT INTO sensitivity(qc_isotope) VALUES ('TC') ;

SELECT * FROM sensitivity;
```

Result:

```
CREATE DOMAIN
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "sensitivity_id_seq" for serial column "sensitivity.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "sensitivity_pkey" for table "sensitivity"
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  value for domain qc_iso violates check constraint "qc_iso_check"
INSERT 0 1
 id | qc_isotope 
----+------------
  2 | TC
(1 row)
```

UPDATE: it does appear that `DOMAIN`s can be changed once they are used (this works on PG-9.1):

```
ALTER DOMAIN QC_ISO
        DROP CONSTRAINT QC_ISO_check -- I don't think the name is important
        ;

ALTER DOMAIN QC_ISO
        ADD CONSTRAINT QC_ISO_check CHECK (value IN ('TC', 'TL', 'AA' ))
        ;
INSERT INTO sensitivity(qc_isotope) VALUES ('AA') ;
INSERT INTO sensitivity(qc_isotope) VALUES ('BB') ;


SELECT * FROM sensitivity;
```

New result:

```
ALTER DOMAIN
ALTER DOMAIN
ERROR:  value for domain qc_iso violates check constraint "qc_iso_check"
INSERT 0 1
 id | qc_isotope 
----+------------
  2 | TC
  4 | AA
(2 rows)
```

Comment: As much as I love the domain concept, the fact that the definition cannot be changed once it is used in a table makes it a bit cumbersome to use.

Comment: You are right. I was referring to the definition of the datatype which you cannot change e.g. from `varchar(20)` to `varchar(50)` if you decided later that you need more characters. A possible workaround is an unbounded type with a check constraint though.

Comment: The UDT datatypes are painful. Unfortunately, they are needed e.g. for GIS. Upgrading will cause headaches: lots of dynamic SQL and poking around in the catalogs.